# eBay API aspectFilter with MaxPrice parameter returns 0 results

Tags: ebay-api

I am using the following URL to fetch car listing. But when I add the `MaxPrice` parameter It shows 0 items. But on the site there are 12 items that have price below my value.

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.12.0&SERVICE-NAME=FindingService&SECURITY-APPNAME=prosoftda-d112-4c99-9bec-8a09c902a7a&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=50&categoryId=6001&outputSelector=PictureURLSuperSize&REST-PAYLOAD=true
&aspectFilter(0).aspectName=Make&aspectFilter(0).aspectValueName=Audi
&aspectFilter(1).aspectName=Model&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName=Q7
&aspectFilter(2).aspectName=Model+Year&aspectFilter(2).aspectValueName=2013
&aspectFilter(3).aspectName=MaxPrice&aspectFilter(3).aspectValueName=50000.00
```

When I remove `MaxPrice` parameter the URL works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Btw, I got the solution for this question: 
To pass the price value need to pass as **ItemFilter**. not with the AspectFilter.

I replace the string :

```
&aspectFilter(3).aspectName=MaxPrice&aspectFilter(3).aspectValueName=50000.00
```

By the string :

```
&itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(0).value=500000.00
```

So It works now. As Price parameter is related to attribute so need to pass with the ItemFilter.

So final URL Is:

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.12.0&SERVICE-NAME=FindingService&SECURITY-APPNAME=prosoftda-d112-4c99-9bec-8a09c902a7a&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=50&categoryId=6001&outputSelector=PictureURLSuperSize&REST-PAYLOAD=true
&aspectFilter(0).aspectName=Make&aspectFilter(0).aspectValueName=Audi
&aspectFilter(1).aspectName=Model&aspectFilter(1).aspectValueName=Q7
&aspectFilter(2).aspectName=Model+Year&aspectFilter(2).aspectValueName=2013
&itemFilter(0).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(0).value=500000.00
```

Thanks. may be this can help someone who is finding the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this API so this is just a shot in the dark. But I found this link:
http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html

From what Ive read within that MaxPrice is more of an "itemFilter" (things such as maxPrice, bestOfferOnly, featuredSeller) than an "aspectFilter" (things such as Make, Model, Optical Zoom).

Further down it also states that some itemFilters need a paramName, such as maxPrice

```
For example, if you use the MaxPrice itemFilter, you will need to specify
a parameter Name of Currency with a parameter Value that specifies the type
of currency desired.
```

Again never used this API but seems relevant to me.

Comment: Currency is an Optional value.

Comment: I had checked using the currency value element with it but its not working. If we didn't pass any currency value API take USD as default.